# DataRow[] itemsarray

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow

I can't seem to be able to be access elements that my DataRow has pulled from my DataTable, I haven't had that much practice with c# either

This is my code:

`DataRow[] results = dt.Select("[Acc No] = '"+ search +"'");`

I have tried casting teh objects from datarow to a string but that was not working.
Search is just a string from a textbox.

When debugging i can see the items array with all the data in it so i know the select is working, can anyone help?

Comment: Well what is its contents in the debugger?

Comment: Also, using teh instead of the will likely not get you help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide more code that that... Such as how you're trying to access the contents of a `DataRow`. To get a value out of the row, I believe the syntax would be something like results[rowNumber][columnNumber/name]

I.e. `results[0][0]` to get the first column value out of the first row, or `results[0]["Id"]` to get the "Id" column from the first row.

Of course you should check `results.Count()` before attempting to access the `DataRow` array.